# Kotlin null-safety is ignored when using Retrofit Gson Converter for parsing Json data (serialization)

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, kotlin-null-safety

I noticed that the following code doesn't throw expectation when server doesn't send any data I expect:

```
override suspend fun forgotPasswordCheckCode(phone: String, code: String): String {
    return try {
        authApi.forgotPasswordCheckCode(
            NetworkForgotPasswordCheckCodeRequest(
                phone = phone,
                code = code
            )
        ).data.verificationToken
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        throw ... // parse http error logic, but doesn't catch it here
    }
}
```

repository:

```
override fun forgotPasswordCheckCode(phone: String, code: String): Flow<String> = flow {
    val token = authDataSource.forgotPasswordCheckCode(phone, code)
    emit(token)
}
```

at the domain layer I map it like this (in a use case):

```
inline fun <reified T> Flow<T>.wrapAsResult(): Flow<Result<T>> {
    return this
        .map<T, Result<T>> {
            Result.Success(it)
        }
        .onStart { emit(Result.Loading) }
        .catch { error ->
            Timber.e(error, "Flow")
            emit(Result.Error(error))
        }
}
```

Serialized data

```
data class NetworkForgotPasswordCheck(
    @SerializedName("verificationToken")
    val verificationToken: String,
)

data class NetworkDataResponse<T>(@SerializedName("data") val data: T)
```

Retrofit:

```
@POST("Auth/verify/sms/password/complete")
suspend fun forgotPasswordCheckCode(
    @Body checkCodeRequest: NetworkForgotPasswordCheckCodeRequest
): NetworkDataResponse<NetworkForgotPasswordCheck>
```

Right now we have the issue on the server side and it sends 200 HTTP-code when sms-code is invalid, yes, a backend developer should fix it, send 4** HTP code instead, but why my Android code doesn't catch nullable value? On the UI/ViewModel I get `null` value and then app crashes because I get `Result.Success(null)` basically and when try to use `result.data`. I didn't set `String?` anywhere, I set `String`.

```
<-- 200 https://.../Auth/verify/sms/password/complete (84ms)
{"data":{"message":"Unable to verify subject with given code"}}
```

I recently updated Kotlin from `1.8.*` to `1.9.0`, could it be the issue?

```
[versions]
kotlin = "1.9.0"
okhttpBom = "4.10.0"
retrofit = "2.9.0"
```

Comment: What are you using for JSON parsing with Retrofit? If the answer is Gson, that is your problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, `retrofit-converter-gson`. But previously I didn't notice such issues, it would catch it as exception if I expect non-nullable String fields in a  model

Comment: I don't see how. Gson is a Java library and as such knows nothing about Kotlin nullability. FWIW, I have been dealing with this issue for years with `retrofit-converter-gson`, because I haven't taken the time to migrate this particular project over to Moshi.

Comment: @CommonsWare mb it was working when API would explicitly send `{ "stringField": null }` but I was expecting non-nullable String. Yeah, it's hard for me right now to migrate to a different serialization lib because of having Gson TypeAdapters and Gson Custom Query Converters

Comment: This is a known issue of Gson. When you use Gson you sort of need to make all fields nullable if you don't want to run into these kind of issues, unless you are 100% sure that the API always returns non-null values